# Add math equations to word file using python

Tags: python, math, ms-word, python-docx

Is there a way to add math equations (containing integration and fractions etc.) to a `.docx` file using Python?

For example:
I want to write

```py
integrate(integrate(x**2/y**2*dx*dy,-1,1),-1,1)
```

in Python and I want to get
An output like this:

[image: a]

Comment: Please, **please**, read tags' usage guidance before using them. The one of [[tag:word]] specifically says: *"A word is the amount of data that a processor can fit in its general-purpose registers -- effectively the amount of data the processor can handle "at once". Programming-related questions concerning Microsoft Word should NOT use this tag - __use the tag [ms-word] instead__"* (already retagged)

Comment: Additionally, the one of [[tag:integration]] says: *"The process of linking together different computing systems and software applications physically or functionally, to act as a coordinated whole. __For numerical integration problem, please use tag [numerical-integration]__"*